# Android Error Zygote setruid failed. errno2

Tags: android

I am getting a Zygot error when I try to execute my helloworld application.

```
05-02 15:32:49.067: ERROR/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 2 
05-02 15:33:14.048: ERROR/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 17 
05-02 15:33:17.798: ERROR/BatteryService(70): usbOnlinePath not found 
05-02 15:33:17.798: ERROR/BatteryService(70): batteryVoltagePath not found 
05-02 15:33:17.798: ERROR/BatteryService(70): batteryTemperaturePath not found 
05-02 15:33:17.890: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(70): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake 
05-02 15:33:18.278: ERROR/SensorService(70): couldn't open device for module sensors (Invalid argument) 
05-02 15:33:31.228: ERROR/EventHub(70): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter 
05-02 15:33:31.228: ERROR/EventHub(70): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter 
05-02 15:33:31.269: ERROR/System(70): Failure starting core service 
05-02 15:33:31.269: ERROR/System(70): java.lang.SecurityException 
05-02 15:33:31.269: ERROR/System(70): at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method) 
05-02 15:33:31.269: ERROR/System(70): at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146) 
05-02 15:33:31.269: ERROR/System(70): at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72) 
05-02 15:33:31.269: ERROR/System(70): at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:206) 
05-02 15:33:32.729: ERROR/SoundPool(70): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg 
05-02 15:33:32.758: ERROR/SoundPool(70): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg 
05-02 15:33:32.768: ERROR/SoundPool(70): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg 
05-02 15:33:32.819: ERROR/SoundPool(70): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg 
05-02 15:33:32.837: ERROR/SoundPool(70): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg 
05-02 15:33:33.002: ERROR/UsbObserver(70): java.lang.NullPointerException 
05-02 15:33:33.002: ERROR/UsbObserver(70): at com.android.server.UsbObserver.init(UsbObserver.java:131) 
05-02 15:33:33.002: ERROR/UsbObserver(70): at com.android.server.UsbObserver.(UsbObserver.java:65) 
05-02 15:33:33.002: ERROR/UsbObserver(70): at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:402) 
05-02 15:33:35.457: ERROR/ThrottleService(70): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf 
05-02 15:33:40.827: ERROR/logwrapper(135): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory 
05-02 15:33:40.907: ERROR/logwrapper(136): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory 
05-02 15:33:41.230: ERROR/logwrapper(137): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory 
05-02 15:34:27.749: ERROR/ActivityManager(70): Start proc com.android.defcontainer for service com.android.defcontainer/.DefaultContainerService: pid=215 uid=10003 gids={1015, 2001}Load: 4.88 / 1.45 / 0.5 
05-02 15:34:27.749: ERROR/ActivityManager(70): CPU usage from 15ms to 11235ms later:
```

File1

```
public class sayhi extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
   }
}
```

File 2

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/textview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:text="@string/hello"/>
```

File 3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello World, sayhisdadas</string>
    <string name="app_name">HelloWorld</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 3):

If your application actually runs, it's no big deal.

If you tried launching your virtual device from AVD, you'd find that it also displays the Zygote error, even without your app.

If your application doesn't run, then you have an issue in your code, but it is still unrelated to the Zygote message.

Precision: Zygote tells you that the setreuid call which "sets effective user ID" failed.
On Linux, which Android is, two documented error codes are 2 and 17, which mean:

```
EINVAL
    The value of the ruid or euid argument is invalid or out-of-range. 
EPERM
    The current process does not have appropriate privileges, and either an attempt was made to change the effective user ID to a value other than the real user ID or the saved set-user-ID or an attempt was made to change the real user ID to a value not permitted by the implementation.
```